# Whether to use FOSRestBundle or just json_encode()?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am creating an API with Symfony 2. I'm using FOSRestBundle for this. Since the bundle and `json_encode()` return the same result, why should I use the bundle?

Why shouldn't I use `json_encode()` to encode the array into JSON for returning the response?

Comment: `JSONResponse` would be preferable to `json_encode()` as it creates the correct response object and set the headers rather than having to do it all manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why should i use the bundle?

Well depends on what your requirements are. If you're trying to develop restful APIs or some fancy things like that you should definitely go with the bundle. If you're just trying to display some json data to the front end just go with a simple `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the biggest advantage is that you don't need to take care of the data-structure using the bundle you will get valid json structures, furthermore it provides functionality to configure the request your are sending (header data, etc) 
So if you are working with more than one or two simple request it might be easier using the bundle, however you will need some time in the beginning for a suitable setup